# Eclipse with EclipseLink: How?

Tags: java, eclipse, installation, eclipselink

I am using ubuntu. I want to build a JPA project with eclipse. According to that [tutorial](http://www.javawebtutor.com/articles/jpa/jpa_crud_example.html) I need to have EclipseLink.
Therefore I went to EclipseLink download page, got .zip achive and tried to follow [instuctions](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.6/solutions/install002.htm#CHDFDCDC) - set the paths.

> JAVA_HOME - Set JAVA_HOME to where you installed your Java SDK home >directory
>   UNIX example: `JAVA_HOME = ...:/usr/java/jdk`
>   PATH - Set PATH to include JDK/bin directory.
>   UNIX example: `PATH = ...:/usr/java/jdk/bin`

okay. My SDK Eclipse, and it is located in /usr/lib/eclipse. Though I also have  /usr/lib/java/swt-gtk-3.8.jar. What should I use here?

Next. Then I take unziped eclipselink folder. It is written, that I should make path to it:

> UNIX example: `ECLIPSELINK_HOME = ...:/usr/el/INSTALL_DIR/eclipselink`

So, for example, I place it like this:

```
ECLIPSELINK_HOME=/home/laura/lib/eclipselink
```

Please, help me. Are my steps correct? What I need to do after set all paths?

Answer (score 0):

So, here you are. The answer qas quite simple: I should have had installed the newest version of Eclipse, where I would have an option to make a JPA project. Then goes an option to choose a platform, EclipseLink, for example.